# comparing __FILE__ with $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] before sending header

Tags: php, headers

I am new to PHP, I saw a code which has the following lines, what is the code trying to de here.

```
if (basename(__FILE__) === basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
   header("Location: https://example.com/");
   exit();
}

include 'config.php';
```

If you provide an article or a resource it will be great.